# Изменение значений в базе данных

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql

У меня есть форма. На ней есть два ComboBox-а. Мне нужно считать с них данные и изменить в таблице. Собственно есть команда:

```
NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE \"Object_nedvizimosti\" " +
                                      "SET \"status\" = :status" +
                                      "WHERE \"object_code\" = :object_code;", con);
```

Но не понятно как считать данные и добавить их в запрос.

Answer (score 1):

где то, так:

```
var query = $"UPDATE \"Object_nedvizimosti\" " +
                        $"SET \"status\" = :status" +
                        $"WHERE \"object_code\" = :object_code;";

var com = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
var status = comboBox_status.Text.Trim();
var object_code = comboBox_object_code.Text.Trim();

int object_code_integer;
bool success  = int.TryParse(object_code, out object_code_integer);

try
{
    com.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("status", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
    com.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("object_code", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Text));
    com.Parameters[0].Value = status;
    if(success)
    {
       com.Parameters[1].Value = object_code_integer;
    }
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (NpgsqlException e) 
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message + '\n');
}
```

Comment: Используйте параметры.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, подробней можно

Comment: Прямая передача даных в sql-запрос путем склеивания строк чревата sql-инъекциями. К тому же запросы с параметрами обычно эффективней, т. к. план запроса кешируется. Как это делается: [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24287396/5045688) (первая попавшаяся ссылка). Кстати, там тоже косяк: после `where` тоже должен быть параметр. Вот еще [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9557823/5045688).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, думаю исправился

Comment: Нет. Это ничего не меняет.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, что скажете?)

Comment: Совсем другое дело.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, Спасибо)

Comment: что такое е? "catch (NpgsqlException e)"

Comment: catch это блок где обрабатываются исключения, NpgsqlException это тип исключения которое можно обработать в блоке catch, если потребуется

Comment: Это я понял, я именно про букву е в конце

Comment: это переменная через которую можно посмотреть допустим трассировку

Comment: но в данном коде она негде не инициализирована и не применяется. я могу её убрать или как её заменить чтобы не было ошибок?

Comment: не нужно ее убирать, теперь будет она использоваться и в дебаг консоль выбрасывать сообщения!

Comment: Проблема в том, что если она есть, то программа выдает ошибку, так как не знает не о какой букве е

Comment: вы серьезно, убирите тогда, будет без обработки ошибок выполнятся код

Comment: А не подскажите, как можно теперь статус в цифру превратить, я конечно написал условие, но изменения в бд не происходит. я знаю про int.Parse, но не знаю куда его здесь применять.

Comment: я дополнил ответ!)

Comment: работает, все??)

Comment: к сожалению не работает, ошибок не выдает, но значение не меняется

Comment: не понятно почему, проблема где то в другом месте