# Как получить название столбцов SQL запроса в postgresql?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

Мне нужно получить имена столбцов после запроса, чтобы их вывести в компонент `dataGridView1`.

Для получения и заполнения имён столбцов таблицы использую :

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
object a = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
sql = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '" + a + "'";            
NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
con.Open();
NpgsqlDataReader reader;
reader = com.ExecuteReader();

ArrayList nameColumns = new ArrayList();
while (reader.Read())
{
    try
    {
        nameColumns.Add(reader.GetValue(0));                   
    }
    catch { }
}
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = nameColumns.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < nameColumns.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = nameColumns[i].ToString();
}
con.Close();
```

Но как получить название столбцов с результатом работы запроса, если учесть, что запрос на несколько таблиц?

Comment: [GetName](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlDataReader_GetName_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имя столбца можно получить с помощью метода GetName.

Прямая передача данных в sql-запрос путем склеивания строк чревата sql-инъекциями. К тому же запросы с параметрами обычно эффективней, так как план запроса кэшируется. Вот здесь еще можно посмотреть: [Изменение значений в базе данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/898113/261244)

```
    static void Npgsql(String connection)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        Object a = comboBox1.SelectedItem;

        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connection))
        {
            String sql = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = :a";
            NpgsqlCommand com = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue(":a", a);
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

            ArrayList nameColumns = new ArrayList();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (Int32 i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        nameColumns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = nameColumns.Count;
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < nameColumns.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText = nameColumns[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ясно, а можно хотя бы короткий пример для запроса  SELECT idgame FROM games EXCEPT SELECT idgame FROM gamelibrary  Что бы я понял, как считывать название столбцов с запроса.

Comment: Имена считываются с результирующего набора, то есть SELECT idgame FROM